# How can I disable / overrride the Wireframe and Stats key in OpenSceneGraph?

Tags: c++, openscenegraph

I inherited a decent-sized code base that has a subpar camera control scheme.  I'd like to use WASD for controls, but W is for wireframe and S is for statistics.  The only solution I could find was:

```
viewer.setKeyEventSetsDone(0);
```

But this doesn't work (or I have it in the wrong place).

What's the easiest way to accomplish disabling wireframe and statistics?  (Or even better remapping them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects that consume the W and S events are two "events handlers", in particular:

- StatsHandler, for which you can set the toggle key with [this method](https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/blob/master/include/osgViewer/ViewerEventHandlers#L90)
- StateSetManipulator, refer to [this method](https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/blob/master/include/osgGA/StateSetManipulator#L83)

Check your code base, you will see them attached to the main osg viewer or one of its views.

Comment: This led me to the answer.  They were calling a (new StatsHandler) under viewer->addEvent().  I created an osgviewer::StatsHander *sh = new osgviewer::StatsHandler, then called sh->setKeyEventTogglesOnScreenStats('p') and modified viewer->addEvent(sh);.  Worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Heres the answer well formated

```
osgViewer::StatsHandler *sh = new osgViewer::StatsHandler;
sh->setKeyEventTogglesOnScreenStats('p');
osggl->addEventHandler(sh);
```